# How to I run molecule testing for a specific or custom platform?

Tags: ansible, molecule

I do know that I can add multiple `platforms` inside `molecule.yml` but something I may want to run a test on a new/experimental one, or I may have one platform which is not freely available so I cannot commit changes to the molecule.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Molecule supports expansion of environment variables inside `molecule.yml` file. This means that you can use this to override default platforms.

Here is a sample content you could use to enable you overrides:

```
platforms:

  - name: ${MOLECULE_PLATFORM:-centos7}
    hostname: ${MOLECULE_PLATFORM:-centos7}
    image: ${MOLECULE_IMAGE:-centos:7}
    registry:
      url: ${MOLECULE_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL:-docker.io}
```

When these variables are not defined, the defaults will be used.